# File Based Processing versus REST API

Tags: api, batch-processing

We have a requirement where we need to process 10,000 transactions once daily in an offline (non real time mode).

Which of the 2 options are preferable

1. A batch file with 10,000 rows sent once a day and processed

or

1. An API call in small batches (as I am presuming sending 10K rows at once is not an option).

I was advised by my architects that option 1 is preferable and an API would only make sense when batch sizes are small - as the disadvantage of 2 is that the person calling the API has to break the payload down into small chunks when they have all the information available to them at once.

I am keen to see how "2" could be a viable option so any comments/suggestion to help make the case would be very helpful.

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: Windows Batch files (is that what you meant?) are inherently slower than a compiled language.  It would depend if speed is a criterion and if the process otherwise takes too long.

Comment: each row takes .25-.5 seconds , however we do envision this to be "offline" processing and not "online"

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer.  However, I would like to mention one reason in favor of REST API: Validation.  This is better managed through the API.  Once the file is dropped into an FTP location, it will be your responsibility to validate the format of the file.  Will it be easy to route a "bad" file back to its source with a message to explain the bounce back?

With an API call, if the representation coming in does not adhere to a valid schema e.g. XML, json, etc. then your service can respond with a: "400 Bad Request" http status code.  This keeps the responsibility of sending data in a valid format with the consumer of the service and helps to achieve a better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 2):

Additional reasoning for a REST API:

Since your file contains transactions, each record should be atomic (If this were not true e.g. there are relationships between the records in the file, then those records should not be considered "transactions").  Therefore, chunking the file up into smaller batches should be trivial.

Regardless, you can define a service that accepts transactions in batch and respond with an HTTP status code of "202 Accepted".  A 202 code indicates that the request was received and will be processed asynchronously.  Therefore, the response can also contain callback links to check the status of individual transactions; or the batch as a whole.  At that point, you would be implementing HATEOAS (Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State) and be in a position to automate the entire process and report on status.

Alteratively with batch files, if the file passes an upfront format validation check, then you'll still have to process each transaction individually downstream.  Some records may load, others may not.  My assumption is the records that fail to load would still need to be handled.  And, you may need to provide the users a view of what succeeded vs. failed.  Now, this can all be handled outside the REST API.  However, the API pattern is simple and elegant IMHO to this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Using Batch Process is always a better idea. you can trigger batch process using REST API.

With Batch processing you can always send an email with msg "improper file format" or you can also send "Which records processed and which did not" . With Rest you cannot keep track records and transactions.

As mentioned in above comment you can use Rest API to trigger a batch Process asynchronously and send the status response using HATEOAS.

SPRING BATCH + SPring REST using SPring BOOT

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question and all answer I found the same subjective answer. I would like put some ideas to compare both concepts:

1. Batch solution requires more storage than REST API. You will need
   store your results on intermediate storage area, and write it on an
   open format. Perhaps you can compress it, but you are changing
   storage with processing.
2. REST API could use more network bandwidth than batch solution, only
   if the intermediate storage is not in network drive. Fetch request,
   and query pooling could require a lot of network bandwidth,
   but could be solved with web-hooks or web-sockets.
3. REST API is easiest to automatic recovery than batch solution. REST
   API response code can help to take automatic decision to recover
   from a FAIL. And you reduce the number of services required to
   identify it. If the network is down an email could fail as REST API.
   And REST API help you to define a good API on these cases.
4. REST API can manage high number of rows as any other TCP protocol
   (as FTP). But in case of any fail you will need logic to manage it.
   It means the REST API will require a chunk enabled protocol too. For
   batch service, this logic is in FTP protocol, but with his own
   logic, not your business logic.
5. Batch service does not require to reserve an instance all time
   (CPU, IP address, port, etc), just
   run when it is needed. You will need a scheduler to start it, or men
   force. Or a man to restart it if it fails. Again, out of scheduler,
   it is not natural to automatize.
6. Batch service does not require more security setup from developer
   side: REST API must take care about authentication. Also, must think
   on injection or other attack methods. REST API could be use helper
   services to prevent all of this, but it means more configuration.
7. Batch services are easy to deploy. Batch services could run on your
   machine, or a server and run it when business need. REST API requires
   continues health check, use a deployment strategy to keep it up, take
   care about DNS configuration, etc. Check if your company give you all
   this services.
8. If this solution is for your company, check what your company is
   doing. Right now there is a common policy to move to REST API, but
   if your support team do not know about it but has a lot of
   experience with batch solution, could be a good idea do not improve.